# How to get Allocated size of the page when keyboard is active?? - Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement of creating views on orientation change. I have used **OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)** method to detect orientation change. When I rotate my device to landscape mode while entry view is focused and keyboard is active, the height value just returns wrong value. Since portrait width and height of the device is different from landscape width and height How can I get the landscape height of the device??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **SoftInput.AdjustPan** in my MainActivity prevents the page from changing the page allocation size when keyboard pops up..  :)

```
WindowSoftInputMode=SoftInput.AdjustPan
```

Comment: Adding this to my MainActivity throwing error : "WindowSoftInputMode doesn't exist in current context". How to use this.